# Extraction of data after calculating the difference of column dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

My condition is if difference of `(f.fit_chk_dt, f.fit_valid_to)>366` and `(o.regn_dt,f.fit_chk_dt)>731` then all records of all columns in fitness and owner tables should be fetched.

This is my select:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM vt_fitness f
LEFT JOIN vt_owner o ON o.regn_no=f.regn_no AND o.off_cd=f.off_cd AND 
    o.state_cd=f.state_cd 
    WHERE f.state_cd='X' 
      AND extract(year from age(f.fit_chk_dt, f.fit_valid_to))>366 
      AND extract(year from age(o.regn_dt, f.fit_chk_dt))>731
 GROUP BY f.regn_no, o.regn_dt, f.fit_chk_dt, f.fit_valid_to
```

Comment: Add table structure and sample output in your question

Comment: The expression `extract(year from age(..))` is not doing what you think it is. You should rewrite that to f.fit_chk_dt - f.fit_valid_to > interval '366 year'`

Comment: @AkhileshMishra Data type of fit_chk_dt and fit_valid_to --timestamp without time zone, and regn_dt is of Date type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Stating "this did not work" is about the most useless statement to be made. To resolve it you need to provide 2 pieces of information **exactly what you got** and **what did you expect**; and why you think what you got is wrong can be useful as well.  
That said however I would guess the error stems from your initial misunderstanding of what the AGE function returns.  AGE returns an interval with years, months, days... You then extract years from the interval want difference between the dates to be greater than ***366 years*** and ***731 years*** respectively. (Side note: That is why @a_horse_with_no_name specified  "interval '366 years'") There in lies your problem. Your data does not span over 731 years.

 
I suspect that what is 1 and 2 years respectively (366 days ~= 1 year, 731 days ~= 2 years (366+365)).   Perhaps:

```
select * 
  from vt_fitness f
  left join vt_owner o 
         on o.regn_no=f.regn_no 
        and o.off_cd=f.off_cd 
        and o.state_cd=f.state_cd 
 where f.state_cd='x' 
   and age(f.fit_chk_dt, f.fit_valid_to) > interval '1 year' 
   and age(o.regn_dt, f.fit_chk_dt) > interval '2 year' 
 group by f.regn_no, o.regn_dt, f.fit_chk_dt, f.fit_valid_to;
```